# реализация tf-idf c#

Tags: c#, строки

Нужна помощь, пожалуйста. Нужно вычислить idf для конкретного текста в richtexbox (tf есть). Для этого нужно еще альтернативные тексты, для которых нужно опять рассчитать tf и выбрать более подходящие альтернативные тексты, где встречаются такие же слова как в первом тексте и для первого текста вычислить idf (то есть число документов в коллекции / число документов в коллекции, в которых встречается слово) и вывести в datagrid. Собственно проблема в том, что не могу понять как это грамотно все реализовать.
TF реализую так:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var word = richTextBox2.Text;
        double length = word.Length;
        var value = word.Split(' ');//розділяє рядок на пробіли і зберігає у змінну 
        Dictionary<string, int> pairs = new Dictionary<string, int>();//колекція ключів та значень
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)//розбитий рядок
        {
            //перевірити, чи слово вже існує у словнику та оновити к-сть
            if (pairs.ContainsKey(value[i]))
            {
                int v = pairs[value[i]];
                pairs[value[i]]++;
            }
            //якщо слово повторюється і не додано до словника, додати його
            else
            {
                pairs.Add(value[i], 1);
            }
        }
        //виводимо

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyValue in pairs)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value, Math.Round(keyValue.Value / length, 5));
        }

    }
```

Comment: tldr для начала покажите тз и mcve, чтобы понять, чтотакое idf/tf

Comment: [Статья](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2013/09/13/tf-idf-in-c-net-for-machine-learning-term-frequency-inverse-document-frequency/), [пример кода](https://github.com/primaryobjects/TFIDF/tree/master/TFIDFExample)

Comment: Извините, не совсем поняла, что показать?